# How do I use variables for chunk options?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am attempting to evaluate a variable after executing an R chunk to define the size chunk options.

````r
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---

```{r setup}
library("tidyverse")

theme_set(theme_bw())
theme_update(strip.background = element_blank())

knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = "80%",
                      out.height = "80%",
                      eval.after = c("fig.height", "fig.width"))
```

# Example chunk attempting to eval.after

```{r fig.width=figWidth, fig.height=figHeight}
plt <- ggplot(iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           y = Sepal.Width,
           color = Petal.Length/Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol = 1)
figWidth <- 7*max(ggplot2::ggplot_build(plt)$layout$layout$COL)
figHeight <- 3.5*max(ggplot2::ggplot_build(plt)$layout$layout$ROW)
plt
```
````

Example of the error:

```
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> eval_lang -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

[image]

I see that I get two main error: one from quartz() device and one from R Markdown. The quartz() error occurs regardless of whether I try to use the variables from the same code chunk or if I try to use call the variables in a subsequent chunk

````r
```{r fig.width=figWidth, fig.height=figHeight}
plt
```
````

Comment: Please do not post (*just*) an image of errors: it cannot be searched (SEO) and it breaks screen-readers. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Sorry, wanted to capture both the error thrown by R Markdown and the quartz() device

Comment: Ok ... I think that's good, but it also will help SEO and screen-readers and such to have the error in the question as plain (code-formatted) text.

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#package-options) `eval.after` is a package option, not a chunk option, so you need to set it with `knitr::opts_knit$set(eval.after = ...)`. For example,

````r
---
title: "eval.after"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(eval.after = 'comment')
```

```{r chunk1, comment=comment_str}
comment_str <- '#$'
1 + 2
```

```{r foo, comment=comment_str}
comment_str <- '#>'
3 + 4
```
````

knits to

[image: knitted document with comment strings defined in chunks]

Comment: Nope, you're using `opts_chunk` instead of `opts_knit`

Comment: Realized that right after I posted the question. I did just try using opts_knit for `fig.height` and `fig.width` and it still does not seem to work. I get a new error message though: `object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`

Comment: No; `fig.height` and `fig.width` are chunk options like `comment`; `eval.after` is a knit option

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - are you saying that it is not possible to use `eval.after` with `fig.height`? If it is possible, could you provide an example of how one would do that in your answer so I can accept it as correct?

Comment: Sure it is; replace `comment` above with `fig.height`, so in your setup chunk you'll have `knitr::opts_knit$set(eval.after = 'fig.height')` (note `knitr::opts_knit`, not `knitr::opts_chunk`), after which in chunk options you can set `fig.height` to expressions that use variables defined in that chunk (or before).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it throws an error as I mentioned above. Does that work in your hands?

Comment: Dug into this, and some options are evaluated before the code regardless of `eval.after`. In this case the problem is line 143 [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/0a77ac2d04ca58fb7f1d3f81f03c885f7d978242/R/block.R#L203), which calls `chunk_device()` which fails on line 314-315; all this happens before code is evaluated on 188 or `eval.after` options are evaluated on line 204. Arguably this is a bug, but given a sized graphics device must be opened before running the code, to fix it would require running it twice, so this is more accurately an undocumented limitation of `eval.after`.

Comment: Thanks so much for digging into this.